# Impossible to use custom fields in twig linked to form

Tags: views, forms, ajax, 9

I have a form in which I have two date fields and a filter button. This form is included in a custom view in which I have a table that displays data from the database. The date fields are here to filter the data that I display in the table. I use AJAX in my form with a callback function.

What I want to do is adding the data to my form with the callback function, and displaying it in my twig.

My problem is that the twig is not updated so I cannot display the data from my form after filtering.

Here is my form :

```
class StatistiqueForm extends FormBase {
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'statistique_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form['date_from'] = array (
            '#type' => 'date',
            '#title' => 'From',
            '#required' => FALSE,
        );

        $form['date_to'] = array (
            '#type' => 'date',
            '#title' => 'To',
            '#required' => FALSE,
        );

        $form['filter_button'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Filter',
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => [$this, 'submitDateFilter'],
                'event' => 'click',
            ],
        );

        $form['reset_button'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',    
            '#value' => 'Reset',
            '#attributes' => array(
                'onclick' => 'this.form.reset(); return false;',
            )
        );
        
        $form['#theme'] = 'form_statistique_form';
        $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    }

    public function submitDateFilter(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form['#statistique_query_data'] = array(
            '#test' => 'test'
        );
    }
}
```

And in the twig, when using `{{ form['#statistique_query_data']['#test'] }}`, nothing is displayed.

I also tried to add `$form_state->setRebuild()` and `\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild()` in *buildForm* and AJAX callback *submitDateFilter* function, but it's not working better.

EDIT : here is a screen of the view :

[image: View]

What I want to do is when clicking on the "Filter" button, add fields to my form in the *submitDateFilter* function and be able to use these fields in the view. For example, with the above code, be able to display in my twig the field `form['#statistique_query_data']['#test']` in one of the tables. But actually, when I click on the "Filter" button, nothing appears when using `{{ form['#statistique_query_data']['#test'] }}` in the twig.

Comment: What is it supposed to render? Or How?

Comment: Hello Kevin, I have just edited the post to add more details. Hope it anwsers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

In my twig, I added a selector on the element I want to modify :

```
<td><p id='element_to_modify'></p></td>
```

In my form, with the AJAX callback function linked to my "Filter" button, I used the AJAX [ReplaceCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21ReplaceCommand.php/class/ReplaceCommand/) to modify my element with any value, using id selector :

```
public function submitDateFilter(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $Selector = '#element_to_modify';
        $content = '<p id=\'element_to_modify\'>new value !</p>';
        $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand($Selector, $content, array()));
        return $response;
    }
```